# RESTKit DELETE request not deleting local object on 2xx success

Tags: restkit-0.20

According to the docs for 0.20 RK:

```
RKManagedObjectRequestOperation adds special behavior to DELETE requests. Upon retrieving a successful (2xx status code) response for a DELETE, the operation will invoke deleteObject: with the operations targetObject on the managed object context. This will delete the target object from the local store in conjunction the successfully deleted remote representation.
```

I have been trying to delete an object with such a request but no matter what I try I can't seem to get it to work. I successfully perform a request for many objects which get mapped to appropriate class, and get stored in core data. When I attempt a delete request on one of the objects and get a 200 success back, it does not deleted from local store.

Here's some code where I am no doubt missing a trick.

**AppDelegate.m**

```
...
//
// Match Mapping
//
RKEntityMapping *matchMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:NSStringFromClass([Match class])
                                                       inManagedObjectStore:objectManager.managedObjectStore];
NSDictionary *matchAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                        @"objectId", @"id",
                                           @"score", @"matchScore",
                                           @"date", @"matchDate",
                                           nil];
matchMapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"objectId"];
[matchMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:matchAttributes];

// Response descriptor for GET
[objectManager addResponseDescriptor:[RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:matchMapping
                                                                                  method:RKRequestMethodGET
                                                                             pathPattern:@"match/"
                                                                                 keyPath:@"matches"
                                                                             statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)]];
// Response Descriptor for PUT
[objectManager addResponseDescriptor:[RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:matchMapping
                                                                                  method:RKRequestMethodPUT
                                                                             pathPattern:@"match/"
                                                                                 keyPath:@"match"
                                                                             statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)]];

// Request Descriptor for DELETE
[objectManager addRequestDescriptor:[RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:[matchMapping inverseMapping]
                                                                          objectClass:[Match class]
                                                                          rootKeyPath:nil
                                                                               method:RKRequestMethodDELETE]];
```

**MatchDetailVC.m**

```
...
- (void)deleteMatch {

NSDictionary *requiredParameters = @{
                                     @"APIKey": @"xxxxx"
                                     };

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] requestWithObject:self.match
                                                                           method:RKRequestMethodDELETE
                                                                             path:@"match/"
                                                                       parameters:requiredParameters];

RKManagedObjectRequestOperation *operation = [[RKObjectManager sharedManager]
                                              managedObjectRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                              managedObjectContext:[RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore].mainQueueManagedObjectContext
                                              success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
                                                  //[[RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore].mainQueueManagedObjectContext save:nil]; // IS THIS NEEDED?
                                                  NSLog(@"Successfully deleted match.");
                                                  [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
                                              }
                                              failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                                  NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                                              }];

 NSOperationQueue *operationQueue = [NSOperationQueue new];
 [operationQueue addOperation:operation];
}
...
```

Thanks in advance and if you need more code, let me know.
Andy

Comment: I've set the `operation.targetObject = self.match` but still no joy. The RKLog does say that the object is being deleted but when watch the SQLite DB nothing changes.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is quite an old post, but here is what I found out after searching for ages...

The local delete will fail if there is no valid response mapping for the DELETE response.
The problem wen't away for me when I created an empty response mapping like this:

```
  RKObjectMapping* nullMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[NSNull class]];
    [objectManager addResponseDescriptor:[RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:nullMapping method:RKRequestMethodDELETE pathPattern:@"mybase/something/:myid/" keyPath:nil statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)]];
```